# C# Return generic abstract class

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following type hierarchy:

```
public interface IDocument<TItem>
{
    IEnumerable<TItem> Query(string query);

    string FileName { get; }
}

public abstract class Document<TDocument, TItem> : IDocument<TItem>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<TItem> Query(string query);

    public string FileName { get; private set; }

    protected readonly TDocument _content;
}

public class DocumentX : Document<string, int>
{
    ...
}

public class DocumentY : Document<string, TypeOther>
{
    ...
}
```

and so on...

And I want to create a factory method, like this:

```
private IEnumerable<IDocument<T>> Factory<T>()
where T : IDocument<T>
{
    yield return new DocumentX();
    yield return new DocumentY();
}
```

The goal is to have a factory method, that will return a collection with different concrete implementations, which are derived from a common interface (IDocument)

But a compiler error raise:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'DocumentX' to 'IDocument'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

What did I miss?

Comment: A `DocumentX` object is a kind of `IDocument<int>`, not a kind of `IDocument<T>`. What are you trying to achieve with your factory method?

Comment: Its exceedingly difficult to know where you are trying to go with this.

Comment: I have extended my post: so my factory should return a collection with different IDocument<T> implementations

Comment: What do you intend to give the generic parameter of `Factory` ?

Comment: Is `TDocument` ever not a `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misuse of generics. If your method is generic, it should not decide what `T` is. The caller decides what `T` is. Right now, your `Factory` method is making assumptions about what `T` exactly is. This shows that `Factory` should not be generic.

What you are trying to say, is something like

> Hey, caller of `Factory`, I'm going to return a bunch of `IDocument<T>`s, but you don't know what the `T` of each one is going to be.

That's what happens when you put both a `DocumentX` and a `DocumentY` into an `IEnumerable`. Imagine that I'm consuming the `IEnumerable` returned by `Factory`. I won't know what kind of document each element I get is. i.e.

```
foreach (IDocument<???> document in Factory()) {
    ??? queryResult = document.Query("some query");
}
```

I will have no idea what I should put in `???`.

Well actually, I do have a *little* idea of what `Query` would return. If I write:

```
foreach (IDocument<object> document in Factory()) {
    object queryResult = document.Query("some query");
}
```

That would work, since everything can be converted to `object`. So we just need to write an `AnyDocument` class that conforms to `IDocument<object>`:

```
public class AnyDocument : IDocument<object> {
    public string FileName { get; private set; }
    private Func<string, IEnumerable<object>> query;

    public IEnumerable<object> Query(string query)
    {
        return this.query(query);
    }

    private AnyDocument() { }
    
    // this is used to convert an `IDocument<T>` to an AnyDocument
    public static AnyDocument FromDocument<T>(IDocument<T> document) {
        var doc = new AnyDocument();
        doc.FileName = document.FileName;
        doc.query = s => document.Query(s).Cast<object>();
        return doc;
    }
}
```

And now you can declare `Factory` like this:

```
private IEnumerable<IDocument<object>> Factory()
{
    yield return AnyDocument.FromDocument(new DocumentX());
    yield return AnyDocument.FromDocument(new DocumentY());
}
```

---

This whole thing could have been a lot simpler if the `T` in `IDocument<T>` is limited to reference types, i.e. no `IDocument<int>` like in `DocumentX`. Because then you can just use generic variance:

```
// just add the word "out"
public interface IDocument<out TItem>
```

Actually, I would say you should do this regardless, because then you can directly return the document objects if `T` is a reference type, and use `AnyDocument` only if `T` is a value type:

```
private IEnumerable<IDocument<object>> Factory()
{
    yield return AnyDocument.FromDocument(new DocumentX());
    yield return new DocumentY(); // let's say "OtherType" is a reference type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
private IEnumerable<IDocument<T>> Factory<T>() where T : IDocument<T>, class
{
    yield return new DocumentX() as T;
    yield return new DocumentY() as T;
}
```

By casting the `DocumentX`, `DocumentY` as `T` you ensure all of them are at least of type `IDcoument<T>`, if not the class `T` which implements `IDocument<T>`.